# How to add a header on the side of listview permanently everytime I add a text?

Tags: java

I am working on a school project that allows users to add reviews. I can add the textview to the listview but I also want to show who added the review so I need a name for the header infront of the review or just a permanent name everytime I add the review. How can I add into it? Example like the coding only show 5/5 rating when i submit the review. But i want it to be Annoymous : 5/5 rating .Even better that user can write they own name on a textview and it will show it together with the review written by the user.Thank in advanced.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);
    txtInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    show = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getInput = txtInput.getText().toString();

            if(addArray.contains(getInput)){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Thank you for your review", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (getInput == null || getInput.trim().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Input Field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                addArray.add(getInput);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ReviewActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
                show.setAdapter(adapter);

                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput)).setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ArrayList is a data structure and TextView is a UI element. You are mixing the types here.

Comment: So using of recycle list with this project is a better choice?

Comment: I did not speak about choices. I have only spoken about the fact that you have spoken about ArrayList like it was a UI element, which shows you are very confused. You might want to read the documentation of these first. That way you will probably be able to answer your question on your own.

Comment: sorry i guess i have mix up with arraylist and listview.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nicholas. I've edited your question to improve its formatting and wording but it's still not crystal clear what are you asking about. If you mixed up something and can now clarify your question, please go ahead by pressing the `edit` button below your post and improve it. Clear and researched questions usually draw more attention and get better answers so I also encourage you to take a https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking Best regards

Comment: Thank alot . It my first time asking question on a forum. Thank for the help ! hope the question is clearer now. with the same example and the result that i want.